# Is there a way to change the default code view size on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-interface, source-code

Do they think we are all working on 1024x768?

I'm running two 24" monitors, giving me a horizontal resolution that can only be described as "obscene", and I *hate* the unnecessary horizontal scrollbars that appear when looking at long lines of code on this site. Is there a way to change it such that it fills out the screen a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1024x768 is the future! Maybe one day we can move to 800x600.

Anyway, I'd check out the Firefox extension Stylish, it allows you to write CSS for websites, so you could change whatever part of the view you don't like with ease.

(Greasemonkey can do more, but overkill)

Comment: yep you can do it with that, thanks. i cant be bothered writing my own css style, but im pretty convinced it would be possible. I've checked out the other styles people have written for SO, no joy there yet.

Answer (score 1):

I zoom in on SO ([Ctrl]+[+]) so that the site fills my screen. Then I set this CSS rule to make the text in the code blocks smaller (though I don't scale any of the other text... yet):

```
.post-text > pre {
  font-size: 0.625em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  max-height: 450px;
}
```

I'm doing this with Greasemonkey just because I'm familiar with it, but there are other extensions you can use to handle just CSS.