# Show sites at size of browser window

Tags: feature-request, design

The SO sites display with a set width to them.  Could we get the display to autosize based on the actual screen display space?  Either automatically, or maybe user-configurable?

I'm not a web-programmer, so I don't know how possible this is or not.

Comment: +1 for size *of browser window*, whereas too many (erroneously) seem to think they should base things on the size *of my computer screen*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hate this, for a number of reasons:

- I like being able to size my browser window to hide the panel on the right without losing question/answer size now and then (mainly when I'm working on two things at once).
- I like knowing approximately how my answers will look in terms of paragraph size and so forth
- I like knowing that syntax highlighter wrapped things correctly
- **Mostly**, I like that this helps encourage brevity in code samples - if the sample is long enough that you're losing code for nesting reasons, it's time to re-focus your thoughts and pare down to just what's relevant to the problem.

Comment: I never thought of it in terms of getting the answer to look a certain way (which I always work hard on also).  I'll have to think about that one.

Comment: I hate scrolling to the right to read long code lines, some of which can't be shortcutted well.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30521/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-code-view-size-on-stack-overflow), this may be a realm for user stylesheets or a greasemonkey script.

Changing the actual design from fixed to fluid presents a number of difficulties, not the least of which is, along the lines of Joel's point, the kind of uglifying stretch that big width tends to give to text content. A reading area too narrow *or* too wide tends to make reading more difficult and less pleasant, and I think SO has hit on a good balance. That being said, it's not impossible to make [an elastic layout](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200504/fixed_or_fluid_width_elastic/) that approximates the current layout and still caps the width at a usable level. We have min-width, we have max-width ([mostly](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t25)), and we have math to figure percentages.

But I doubt that will be or will be perceived to be a trivial update. Fixed width sites have a sort of stability and ease (using percentages means stopping to figure percentages when you update/edit, and worrying about how browsers [might screw it up](http://haslayout.net/css/Percentage-Padding-Margin-Bug)) that is hard to rival. On the other side of things, a user-stylesheet solution has the advantage of only being concerned about one browser (typically), and one user's preferences.